# Are there any other tables with columns in Hive metastore?

Tags: mysql, hive, beeline, hive-metastore

I have 30 fields in

```
describe my_table;
```

in `beeline`. Simultaneously, if I am accessing Hive Metastore, I see 24 columns in `COLUMNS_V2` and 2 columns in `PARTITION_KEYS`. 4 columns are missing. Where can they be? Are there any other tables inside Hive mtastore which can contain data on some special columns?

Comment: can you do `analyze table my_table compute statistics` in hive and see if it updated metadata tables?

Comment: Didn't help. Although I was to use `noscan` option...